# Error while fetching objects from Django model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I want to get all Codes Model objects and count the length of the objects returned. I'm getting an error that I can't understand.

This is my model

```
class Codes(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language
```

I'm using the below function to get all objects from the model

```
def get_all_codes(lang):
    queryset = Codes.objects.filter(language = lang)
    return queryset
```

Calling the function

```
all_codes_of_lang = get_all_codes(lang)
```

and trying to count the length using:

```
if len(all_codes_of_lang) > 0:
    print("abc")
```

leading to this error:

```
if len(all_codes_of_lang) > 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 240, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: relation "submissions_codes" does not exist
LINE 1: ...odes"."code", "submissions_codes"."language" FROM "submissio...
                                                             ^

-->
```

Comment: Your models are out of sync with your database. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not with the `get_all_codes` function or with counting the length, but with a synchronization problem between your models and your database.

Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py` migrate to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The models doesn't migrated that's the reason you got this error.
Run following commands

- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`